# Unable to load JSON data in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I  trying to insert a `JSON` File data into a html table but i dont know where is the problem. I  sharing my javascript code and sharing the json file. Please look the code once

javascript

```
<script>
 function display() {
    $(function() {
       $.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
         $.each(data.courselist , function(i, f) {

           var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Name" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.categoriesId + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Info" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.shortName + "</td>" + "</tr>";
           $(tblRows).appendTo("#category tbody");
     });
   });
});

}
</script>

{"success":true,"courselist":{"categoriesId":[],"shortName":"Geography Environment & Ecology"}}
```

Comment: Could you please update heading of the question?
Load Json NOT Jaon

Comment: uplated now thanks.Now please solve my query

Comment: 1 thing try to search your problem on the platform if you did not found any solution then post question. So many answers are available on platform.
Anyway please alert (i, f) and check what is the value of i and f then you will find solution of your question.

Comment: undefined alerting

Comment: I think using tagging Jquery instead of Javascript would be better

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing JSON in wrong way, please [read this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) & see the snippet:

```js
var data = {"success":true,"courselist":{"categoriesId":[],"shortName":"Geography Environment & Ecology"}};
$.each(data.courselist , function(key, val) {
       var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + key + "</td>" + "<td>" + val + "</td>" + "</tr>";
       //$(tblRows).appendTo("#category tbody");
       console.log(tblRows);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```